# GQL Queries - Retrieving specific data from query object

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

I'm building a database using Google Datastore. Here is my model...

```
class UserInfo(db.Model):

name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
password = db.StringProperty(required = True)
email = db.StringProperty(required = False)
```

...and below is my GQL Query. How would I go about retrieving the user's password and ID from the user_data object? I've gone through all the google documentation, find it hard to follow, and have spent ages trying various things I've read online but nothing has helped! I'm on Python 2.7.

```
user_data = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE name=:1', name_in)
user_info = user_data.get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic Python.

From the query, you get a `UserInfo` instance, which you have stored in the `user_info` variable. You can access the data of an instance via dot notation: `user_info.password` and `user_info.email`.

If this isn't clear, you really should do a basic Python tutorial before going any further.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Treat the query object like a class.

```
name = user_info.name
```

Documentation on queries [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries) gives some examples

Answer (score 0):

There are some python tips that might help you

```
dir(user_info)
help(user_info)
```

you can also print almost anything, like

```
print user_info[0] 
print user_info[0].name
```

Setup logging for your app

[Logging and python etc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)